# PHPExcel right align image

Tags: php, image, alignment, phpexcel

I'm trying to align an image using PHPExcel but i can't because the image is overlaid above the worksheet.

```
// Create new picture object
  $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
  $objDrawing->setPath('my_img.jpg');

// Insert picture
  $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
  $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

// Style cell
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT);
```

The text align of A1 change to right align but the image it still aligned on the left.

Comment: Because images are overlaid on the worksheet rather than content of a cell, you'll need to calculate the position of that image relative to the width of the cell using the images `setOffsetX()` and `setOffsetY()`methods .... setting a cell's alignment relates only to the content of the cell, there is no magic to do this for you.

Comment: @Mark Baker: Well, there's a bit of magic to get around the confusion caused by the fact that Excel uses character units to measure cell width, points (some fraction of an inch) to measure cell height and pixels to deal with pictures. This was extremely confusing for me especially since I don't know what an inch is :-). See my solution below.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same challenge: How to right align a picture to a cell. I am using PHP Spreadsheet which succeeds PHP Excel. This works:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing;

$ws = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet(); 
$logoPath = __DIR__ . '/reporting/templates/SmallLogo.jpg';
$drawing = new Drawing();
$drawing->setPath($logoPath);
$drawing->setCoordinates('K2');
$drawing->setHeight(45); //pixels
$colWidth = $ws->getColumnDimension('K')->getWidth();
if ($colWidth == -1) { //not defined which means we have the standard width
    $colWidthPixels = 64; //pixels, this is the standard width of an Excel cell in pixels = 9.140625 char units outer size
} else {                  //innner width is 8.43 char units
    $colWidthPixels = $colWidth * 7.0017094; //colwidht in Char Units * Pixels per CharUnit
}
$offsetX = $colWidthPixels - $drawing->getWidth(); //pixels
$drawing->setOffsetX($offsetX); //pixels
$drawing->setWorksheet($ws);
```

It should work the same way with PHPExcel. The trick is to convert the column width into Excel pixels and use offsetX to get the right offset from the left horizontal column border. The offset will be negative if the picture is wider than the column.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that PHPExcel/PHPSpreadsheet do have a set of functions for unit conversions (pixels/EMU/points/cell dimension) in the PHPExcel_Shared_Drawing (PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Drawing in PHPSpreadsheet) class

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea:

You need to determine the maximum width / height (by experimentation). Save the values.

```
// Logo
$maxWidth = 700;
$maxHeight = 40;
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
$objDrawing->setName("Logo");
$objDrawing->setDescription("Company Logo");
$objDrawing->setPath('logo.png');
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$objDrawing->setHeight($maxHeight);
// This is the "magic" formula
$offsetX =$maxWidth - $objDrawing->getWidth();
$objDrawing->setOffsetX($offsetX);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

you can follow this code to shift the image towards the center with the two lines of special code for (X, Y) relative to the point of  the angle

to change the position of X
`$objDrawing->setOffsetX(100);`

to change the position of Y
`$objDrawing->setOffsetY(20);`

```
$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('image/issam.jpeg');      // path for the picture 
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Logo Absiskey');                   // the name
$objDrawing->setDescription('Logo Absiskey');            // decription 
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(60);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('B10');
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(100);                            // set x position 
$objDrawing->setOffsetY(20);                             // set Y position
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the height of the row manually

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($index)->setRowHeight(100);
```

`$index` is row number.