# phpExcel could not center image in cell

Tags: excel, phpexcel

I am trying to insert an image in the center of the first cell. The cell is a merge from four cells:

```
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:D1');
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('1')->setRowHeight(65);
```

I followed the instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659925/phpexcel-right-align-image) post to center the image.

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sima');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Logo');
$objDrawing->setPath('../img/logo.jpg');
$objDrawing->setOffsetX(300);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$objDrawing->setHeight(80);
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($phpExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

and then save & download the file

```
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, "Excel2007");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
ob_end_clean();
$writer->save('php://output');
```

If I open the generated file with LibreOffice I can see the image in the center but if I open it with Ms Excel 2010 the image is align left.

Any idea???